# How to update XML element for a particular node using php?

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FLOOR>
  <FLOOR1>
<BlOCK ID="F5" NAME="HallMark" URL="F1.COM"/>
<BlOCK ID="F6" NAME="F6" URL="F1.COM"/>
<BlOCK ID="F7" NAME="U.S. Polo Assn." URL="F1.COM"/>
  </FLOOR1>

    <FLOOR2>
<BlOCK ID="G4" NAME="Daiso" URL="G1.COM"/>
<BlOCK ID="G5" NAME="Lakhoos Exchange" URL="G1.COM"/>
<BlOCK ID="G6" NAME="4u" URL="G1.COM"/>
<BlOCK ID="G7" NAME="Aldo" URL="G1.COM"/>
<BlOCK ID="G8" NAME="Athlete's co." URL="G1.COM"/>

    </FLOOR2>
</FLOOR>
```

Above is my XML file. I want to update the element value of  "name" with ID =G8 or say ID=F7 .Please help. I tried many codes.But failed

```
I tried this .. but it returns empty.
$xmlFile = file_get_contents('floormap.xml');
//$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlFile);
$new= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFile);
$n=$new->xpath('//FLOOR1/B1OCK[@ID="F1"]');
var_dump($n);
```

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: Put those ways you tried and failed. Please update your question.

Comment: What it supposed to do? Explain neatly

Comment: I need to update the attribute "name" using the other attribute ID.For eg through a query string i got id value as F6 so i have to update the name attribute to "ch1" and URL to "gmail.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already half way there. Do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$update = $xml->xpath("//BlOCK[@ID='G7']")[0]; // requires PHP >= 5.4
$update['NAME'] = "Michi";
```

If you look at `$xml` now, the `NAME`-attribute of the `<BlOCK>`-node with `ID='G7'` is changed.

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/F9Pte1